# Apache Solr group to return all values

Tags: solr

I am new to Apache Solr and recently started using it. I have a requirement where I need to group on some field and get all the corresponding values of other field. I am using below Solr API.

```
.../select?fl="keyword_field"&group.field="fieldName"&group=true
```

Above Solr API is returning only 1 value per group, which is default behavior of Solr. But what I want is to get all the values per group. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want to be returned for an example document? "all the values per group" means exactly what?

Answer (score 0):

By default Solr limits the number of results in a group to one which is the top document are returned according to the implicit default group.limit=1.

group.limit (Specifies the number of results to return for each group. The default value is 1.)

If you want to get all the docs per group then you should be using group.limit=-1 which collects the maxDocs.